# How to prevent jq from automatically converting double to int?

Tags: json, jq

I have `input_file`:

```
{"hi":48.0, "yep":48.123}
```

I run this

```
jq . < input_file > output_file
cat output_file
```

My output:

```
{
  "yep": 48.123,
  "hi": 48
}
```

I would like the output to be

```
{
  "yep": 48.123,
  "hi": 48.0
}
```

How do I prevent jq from automatically converting my double values to an int?

Comment: https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/1301

Answer (score 2):

jq parses numbers into C doubles.  It then formats them back as numbers.  This conversion is lossy in two ways: a) there are many ways to represent the same number, but jq uses only one and has no options to do otherwise, b) C doubles have finite precision.

There are issues open against jq about both problems.  The likely solution will be to adopt a bignum/bigfloat approach, and to keep the original number string for numbers passed through unmodified (as it were; jq treats all data as copy-on-write).  But that isn't implemented yet.