# How can I avoid jq truncating long decimal

Tags: decimal, jq

How can I prevent jq from truncating long decimal values?

For example:

```
echo '18302628978110292481' | jq .
```

result: 18302628978110292000

Comment: It clearly doesn't have the precision you need. Just treat it as a string.

Comment: This appears to be the best answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575963/how-to-prevent-jq-from-automatically-converting-double-to-int?rq=1

Comment: The link best explains the problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575963/how-to-prevent-jq-from-automatically-converting-double-to-int?rq=1

Comment: Those links do not have any answers. I could not find any solution using the jq, so I decided to do a "find using regex and replace" in the input json file, and enclosed all numbers with quotes to make them strings.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript does not support such big numbers and so does `jq`. The integer size is `2^53`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/171318)

To make it work, you'll need to treat them as strings:

```
echo '"18302628978110292481"' | jq .
# Prints "18302628978110292481"
```